# Mixed model adjusted for lme4

Tags: lme4-nlme

I am trying to fit a mixed model using the library lme4, and is emerging the following error.

fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 10 columns / coefficients.

In this case, I'm using the Effects window and time as factors. If they are considered numeric, the error becomes

fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 2 columns / coefficients.

Follow the syntax used.

```
Modelo1 <-lmer (EREF GROUP ~ + Time + window +
                GROUP:Time +
                GROUP:Window + 
                Time:Window + Time:Window:GROUP + (1 | Subject),
                data = datalong2)
```

From what I see, it is not estimating doi elements of interaction between GROUP: WINDOW.

Does anyone have suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried running lmer(EREF ~ Time + Window + GROUP:Time + GROUP:Window + Time:Window + Time:Window:GROUP + (1 | Subject), data = datalong2)?

Comment: Not yet, but I'll try.

Comment: while framed as an R question, I believe the essential issue here is statistical.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it's just a typo, i.e. specifying `GROUP: + Window` instead of `GROUP:Window`. It would be easier and less error-prone instead to specify `~Time*Window*GROUP-GROUP` ... (are you sure you meant to leave out the main effect of `GROUP`?)

Comment: Removing some interactions, the model would look like, lmer(Eref ~GRUPO+Janela+Time+GRUPO:Janela+(1|Subject), data=datalong1, REML=FALSE),                                   But the following message appears:                                                         fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 2 columns / coefficients
What to do?